# Database delete function not working

Tags: android, database

Hello all I have got somthing wrong while deleting items from database.I have a list of schools in one activity.THis is my screen shot
[![Schools.java][1]][1]

At the top of schooldetails.class I have an star icon to bookmark the school.On clicking the bookmark icon the icon changes to filled one and the respective schools get saved to my bookmark class.Till this everything is working fine.Now I am trying to implement bookmark deletion on re-clicking the filled star icon.I wish to remove the bookmarked school from bookmark class.This is what I did inside Schooldetails class

```
package com.example.user.educationhunt;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.user.educationhunt.database.DatabaseHelper;
import com.example.user.educationhunt.fragment.About;
import com.example.user.educationhunt.fragment.Admission;
import com.example.user.educationhunt.fragment.FeeStructure;
import com.example.user.educationhunt.listner.DatabaseUpdatedListener;
import com.example.user.educationhunt.pojos.Bookmarkitem;
import com.example.user.educationhunt.pojos.OurSchool;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SchoolDetails extends AppCompatActivity implements DatabaseUpdatedListener {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    Boolean isStarFilled = false;
    DatabaseHelper db;
    OurSchool ourSchool;
    private Menu menu;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_school_details);

        ourSchool = (OurSchool) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("school");

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(ourSchool.getSchoolName());


        db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        db.databaseUpdatedListener = this;

        Toast.makeText(this, ourSchool.getSchoolName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.fav_school, menu);
        this.menu = menu;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.star_School:
                Bookmarkitem bookmarkitem = new Bookmarkitem();
                bookmarkitem.setBookmarkID(ourSchool.getSchoolId());
                bookmarkitem.setName(ourSchool.getSchoolName());
                bookmarkitem.setLogo(ourSchool.getSchoolLogo());
                bookmarkitem.setAddress(ourSchool.getSchoolAddress());
                db.addSchoolBookmark(bookmarkitem, item);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        List<Bookmarkitem> bookmarkitems = db.getAllSchoolBookmark();
        if (bookmarkitems.size() != 0) {
            for (Bookmarkitem bookmarkitem : bookmarkitems) {
                if (bookmarkitem.getBookmarkID() == ourSchool.getSchoolId()) {
                    isStarFilled = true;
                    break;
                }
                else isStarFilled=false;
            }
            if (isStarFilled) {
                menu.getItem(0).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.starfilled));
            }else if (isStarFilled.booleanValue()==true){
                delete();
                menu.getItem(0).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.star));
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void delete(){
        List<Bookmarkitem> bookmarkitems = db.getAllSchoolBookmark();
        db.removeBookmarkItem(ourSchool.getSchoolId());    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new About(), "ABOUT US");
        adapter.addFragment(new Admission(), "ADMISSION");
        adapter.addFragment(new FeeStructure(), "FEE");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    @Override
    public void setDatabaseSuccess(String schoolName, MenuItem item) {
        Toast.makeText(this, schoolName + "successfully added as bookmark", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        item.setIcon(R.mipmap.starfilled);
    }

    @Override
    public void setDatabaseError(String failureMessage) {
        Toast.makeText(this, failureMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my database class

```
package com.example.user.educationhunt.database;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.example.user.educationhunt.listner.DatabaseUpdatedListener;
import com.example.user.educationhunt.pojos.Bookmarkitem;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by user on 11/22/2016.
 */
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DatabaseUpdatedListener databaseUpdatedListener;
    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "BookmarkDatabase";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String TABLE_NAME_BOOKMARK = "bookmark";

    //    Contact table columns name
    private static final String ID = "Id";
    private static final String NAME = "Name";
    private static final String LOGO = "Logo";
    private static final String LOCATION = "Location";

    String createTableBookmark = "Create table if not exists `Bookmark` ("
            + "`name`   TEXT," + "`location`    TEXT," + "`logo`    TEXT);";

    String CREATE_SCHOOL_BOOKMARK_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_BOOKMARK + "("
            + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            + NAME + " TEXT, "
            + LOGO + " TEXT, "
            + LOCATION + " TEXT " + ")";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public void insertBookmarkData(Bookmarkitem bookmarkitem) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
        content.put("name", bookmarkitem.name);
        content.put("location", bookmarkitem.address);
        content.put("logo", bookmarkitem.logo);

        db.insert("Bookmark", null, content);
    }

    public ArrayList<Bookmarkitem> getBookmarkist() {
        String sql = "select * from Bookmark ";
        ArrayList<Bookmarkitem> bookmarklist = new ArrayList<Bookmarkitem>();

        Cursor c = getWritableDatabase().rawQuery(sql, null);
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            Bookmarkitem info = new Bookmarkitem();
            info.name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
            info.address = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("location"));
            info.logo = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("logo"));
            bookmarklist.add(info);
        }
        c.close();
        return bookmarklist;
    }

    public Bookmarkitem getBookmarkData(String bookmarkName) {
        String sql = "select * from Bookmark  where id='" + bookmarkName + "'";

        Cursor c = getWritableDatabase().rawQuery(sql, null);
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            Bookmarkitem info = new Bookmarkitem();
            info.name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
            info.address = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("location"));
            info.logo = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("logo"));
        }
        c.close();
        Bookmarkitem info = null;
        return info;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_SCHOOL_BOOKMARK_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME_BOOKMARK);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }

    public void addSchoolBookmark(Bookmarkitem bookmarkitem, MenuItem menuItem) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(ID, bookmarkitem.getBookmarkID());
        values.put(NAME, bookmarkitem.getName());
        values.put(LOGO, bookmarkitem.getLogo());
        values.put(LOCATION, bookmarkitem.getAddress());

        //inserting row
        if (db.insert(TABLE_NAME_BOOKMARK, null, values) != -1) {
            databaseUpdatedListener.setDatabaseSuccess(bookmarkitem.getName(), menuItem);
        } else {
            databaseUpdatedListener.setDatabaseError("Failed to insert");
        }
        db.close();
    }

    public List<Bookmarkitem> getAllSchoolBookmark() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME_BOOKMARK;
        List<Bookmarkitem> bookmarkitems = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Bookmarkitem bookmarkitem = new Bookmarkitem();
                bookmarkitem.setBookmarkID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                bookmarkitem.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                bookmarkitem.setLogo(cursor.getString(2));
                bookmarkitem.setAddress(cursor.getString(3));
                bookmarkitems.add(bookmarkitem);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return bookmarkitems;
    }

    public void removeBookmarkItem(int sID) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME_BOOKMARK + " WHERE " + ID + "= '" + sID + "'");
        db.close();
    }
}
```

In addition to this ,On clicking to the list inside bookmarked class items.I wish to load the details of respective class.This is my bookmark claass

```
package com.example.user.educationhunt;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.user.educationhunt.adapter.BookmarkAdapter;
import com.example.user.educationhunt.database.DatabaseHelper;
import com.example.user.educationhunt.pojos.Bookmarkitem;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Bookmark extends AppCompatActivity {
    private List<Bookmarkitem> ourBookmarkListItems = new ArrayList<Bookmarkitem>();
    private ListView listView;
    private BookmarkAdapter adapter;
    DatabaseHelper dbhelper;
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bookmark);
        dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        toolbar.setPadding(0, getStatusBarHeight(), 0, 0);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Bookmark");

        List<Bookmarkitem> bookmarkedSchools = dbhelper.getAllSchoolBookmark();

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_bookmarked);
        if (bookmarkedSchools.size() != 0) {
            adapter = new BookmarkAdapter(this, bookmarkedSchools);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You have no bookmark yet.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                startActivity(new Intent(Bookmark.this,SchoolDetails.class));
            }
        });

          }

    public int getStatusBarHeight() {
        int result = 0;
        int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        if (resourceId > 0) {
            result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

I am neither getting any error nor proper result.Someone please help

Comment: use a log in your `removeBookmarkItem(int sId)` method in `DatabaseHelper` class to check the value you are getting and crossmatch with the database value. 

`Log.e("DB","sid="+sid);`

Comment: I have used removeBookmarkItem inside delete function in SchoolsDetails class.You can see the code above

Comment: Are you gettitng the ID you wish to delete in this line ? `bookmarkitem.setBookmarkID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));`

Comment: Check `ourSchool.getSchoolId()`, what value displaying ?

Comment: @therameshbista i said put a log in that function to check the value of `sId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in your helper class :D

```
public boolean removeBookmarkItem(String id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete(TABLE_NAME_BOOKMARK, ID + "=" + id, null) > 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check yours delete method through db. You can download DB browser for SQLite and open your db file with this browser and check, if you're really deleting bookmark state, if not maybe there is problem with query.